# Class variable reset with rails / spring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-spring

I've a class defined as such:

```
class PublicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def self.jobs
    @jobs ||= Hash{|h, k| h[k] = []}
  end
  def self.register(format, job_class)
    jobs[format] << job_class
  end
  # [...]
end
```

To register different job classes, I put in an initializer:

```
PublicationJob.register(:tex, SaveJob)
PublicationJob.register(:saved_tex, TexJob)
#...
```

The in the `rails console` I try:

```
PublicationJob.jobs
#> {:tex => [SaveJob], :saved_tex => [TexJob]}
```

But if I exit the console (Ctrl-D) then restart it, at some point the hash will be empty!

**Why is the class variable reset in this case?**

I use rails 4.2.1 and spring, and I know that if I kill/stop spring it works again for some time. Is it related to spring?

Comment: Are you making modifications to files? Because spring reloads these files, and even restarts the application in some cases, causing your data to get wiped.

Comment: I update some files in the app directory, but not even the publication_job :/

Comment: yeah, that could be enough for Spring to reload your app, depending on what you have changed. Thus wiping your data

Comment: But if spring reloads the app, then why doesn't it reload the initializer as well ?

Comment: look at https://github.com/rails/spring#class-reloading  it explains why the data changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. "So to avoid this problem, don't save off references to application constants in your initialization code." In other words, this mean I can't initialize my application. Great !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so this was entirely Spring related, and I fixed it by removing spring.

Thanks to @NekoNova who pointed me to the right part of the documentation, I found [that](https://github.com/rails/spring#class-reloading):

> This saves off the first version of the User class, which will not be the same object as User after the code has been reloaded:
>
> [...]
>
> So to avoid this problem, don't save off references to application constants in your initialization code.

In other words, I can't initialize my classes using initializers, because althought it'll work in production, it won't work in development.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is rather old, but I have encountered this issue a couple of times, and feel that you don't have to abandon spring if you set class level variables at initialization.

All you need to do is re-assign them in a spring ".after_fork" block. So for the above issue, place in a "config/spring.rb" file, the following:

```
if ("Spring".constantize rescue nil)
  Spring.after_fork do
    PublicationJob.register(:tex, SaveJob)
    PublicationJob.register(:saved_tex, TexJob)
  end
end
```

This will reset those variables after spring completes the fork and reloading code. I wrap it in a check to ensure that Spring is available, which it likely won't be in production.